# Localization of data annotations in separate class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, .net-core

We are trying to implement localization for our domain models which are existing in a separate class library project within our solution.
However, we are not able to get it working as our models data annotation attributes doesn't get translated at all.

**Project structure**

- Solution

  - Web project

    - Resource folder (Contains .resx files. *Ex. App.en.resx*) Works fine
  - Class library

    - Domain models
    - Resource folder (Contains .resx files. *Ex. App.en.resx*) Doesn't work

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvc()
     .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
     .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

**Note**

Localization works within the Web project, e.g it translates views, controllers.
However, it doesn't work when we try to translate models which exists in a separate project.

// Regards

Comment: Could you edit you question and put an example of how you are trying to use the resource inside your class library? I'm trying something like `[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_EmailInvalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]` but **MyResources** doesn't seem to exist inside class library, whereas it does in web app. It looks the code for using these strongly typed classes representing resource files are generated automatically when using web app. Maybe this is why in your case it doesn't work at all (it's a shot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support to translate data annotations, views, controller etc that exists in a separate project for now without implementing it by yourself.

The solution is to write your own custom implementation using IStringLocalizer, IStringLocalizerFactory and register it in Startup.cs. [See how StringLocalizer/Factory works.](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization)

FYI: The aspnet team that is working on Localizer is aware of this and is working on a solution to support this in the future. See [aspnet/Localization](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization)

Comment: This may work, but according to the ASP.NET CORE documentation here: docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/…, we should be able to localize these DataAnnotation error messages without specifying resource name and type. Whatever I try, however, I do not mange to get this working. Can someone share some experience on that?